# Travelling through Moscow - visa for transit?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, russia, svo

I am a Norwegian arriving terminal E (from Oslo) and leaving from terminal F (to Beirut) at the Moscow (Sheremetyevo) airport.
Will I need a visa for this travel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, both terminals E and F are designed for international flights and are connected through the corridor which doesn't have any passport control check points.

Check out [the map of the airport](http://www.svo.aero/en/transport/).

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @OleksandrKravchuk is correct **only** if you stay in Sheremetyevo less than 24 hours. If your transfer is longer than that, you'll need the visa. Refer to [official documentation](http://www.svo.aero/en/transit/int-int/) for more details and connection times.